# How to extract specific text on a PDF file with pdfminer.six

Tags: python

Please I need help on how to extract the texts under "Course" and "Grade" from this PDF, [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16REPlZAx3ELfA8nieVwJqj9o9U4lwehd/view?usp=drivesdk)

pdfminer and pdfminer.six seems to be the only modules that work on my PDF and I have tried all my possible best to extract only the texts I want, which are the values of "Course" and "Grade".

I tried...

> > text = extract_text("my_pdf.pdf")
> > print(text)

The outcome of this is not really in same order with the original file, some texts are picked vertically whereas some are horizontally.
However, I tried to extract the text with 6 characters, uppercases, and alphanumeric(after I replaced '\n' with '' and split new line) and the result was successful. But my problem is the grade.  Please help a friend in need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Link: Access denied.

Comment: Access as now been granted to the file. Thanks